# Serialize and deserialize Jackson XML element having the same name

Tags: java, xml, jackson-databind

I am trying to write code and objects to deserialize XML like the listed below using a class `Product`:

```
<list>
  <product id="14032019"><![CDATA[Some text]]></product>
  <product id="14032019" value="Some text"/>
</list>
```

The Product POJO  has the value attribute annotated as follows and it works for these cases:

- `<product id="14032019" value="Some text"/>`:

  ```
  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String value;
  ```
- `<product id="14032019"><![CDATA[Some text]]></product>`:

  ```
  @JacksonXmlCData
  @JacksonXmlText
  private String value;
  ```

But it doesn't seem to work when I combined all the annotations. Does anyone had an issue like this ?

**Edit:**

I tried `@JsonSubTypes` annotation using 2 different child classes that inherit from the parent class and identified separately (I followed the example in https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations).
This approach needs an attribute called `className` in the XML for each tag which is not provided in the original XML.

```
<product className="myPackage.Product1" id="123" value="Some text"/>
<product className="myPackage.Product2" id="123">Some text</product>
```

Is there anyway to write a custom mapper or a deserializer for the case where there's no className attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind the solution is to implement a specific deserializer.

```
public class ProductDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Product> {

  public ProductDeserializer() {
      super(Product.class);
  }

  @Override
  public Product deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
    Product p = new Product();

    while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
        String tokenName = parser.getCurrentName();

        switch (tokenName) {
            case "id":
                parser.nextToken();
                p.setId(parser.getText());
                break;

            // when you encounter an attribute called value or "" you take its value 
            case "value":
            case "":
                parser.nextToken();
                p.setValue(parser.getText().trim());
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return p;
  }
}
```

And you have to register it when you use the `XmlMapper` class :

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("configModule", Version.unknownVersion());
module.addDeserializer(Product.class, new ProductDeserializer());
xmlMapper.registerModule(module)
```

The product POJO has id and value as attributes.